# Can I use 2 DVIs and a DisplayPort for 3 monitors?

Tags: multiple-monitors, dvi, displayport

I have [a Zotac GeForce GTS 450](http://www.newegg.com/Product/Product.aspx?Item=N82E16814500187), can I use three monitors using 2 DVI ports and a DisplayPort with a DisplayPort to DVI converter?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This card, indeed all GTS 450s, only support two simultaneous outputs.  This is due to the design of the chipset itself (the TDMS links are not nearly as flexible as a comparable EyeFinity-supporting AMD card)

Comment: so, how do i know which card actually supports 3+ monitors?

Comment: You research it in advance? Google is your friend. :)  That said, I don't think there are ANY GeForce cards right now that do more than two outputs.  (nVidia does have some quad-output Quadros, though)

Comment: @Shinrai there are a handful of custom card designs that do it.  The Galaxy MDT GTX 580 is one.  I've seen a few others that also added additional hardware to make it work. http://www.hardocp.com/article/2012/01/02/galaxy_mdt_geforce_gtx_580_video_card_review

Comment: @DanNeely - That wasn't the case when I wrote this seven months ago.  Also, the example you give is not true independent outputs: "Similar to the Galaxy MDT X5 GTX 560 Ti video card, Galaxy employs a custom chipset on this video card which combines the three HDMI ports into one large resolution. Windows sees only one large resolution, and not three separate displays. This does not use NV Surround technology, it is literally three output ports combined into one large resolution."